# easiest way make 2 iis web servers public behind 1 router

Tags: windows-10, router, ip, port-forwarding, webserver

Having a problem figuring out the easiest way to pull this off, or if it's even possible..

Just bought a 2nd machine (web server) and I now I want to expose both machines to the public (to run websites via iis).

My DNS (type a) cannot accept a port, so I'm basically stuck with all traffic going to my router on port 80.

And my router can only split traffic via ports as far as I know, so I have to send all my traffic to one machine. Or at least that's all I am smart enough to figure out.

Should that machine then forward traffic to the other machine somehow?

I've heard of reverse proxies, but not sure how to set it up.

Do I need to do something like setup a VPN and expose it to the public?

I need traffic for www.abc.com to go to one machine behind the router. And traffic for www.xyz.com to go to a 2nd machine behind the same router.

Can someone give me some tips on an easy way to pull this off? Or if it's even possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use separate ports. I gave a lot of detail on how to do this transparently in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1274974/327367) to a related question, though you may not need the parts dealing with dynamic DNS. The alternative is to have one machine receive all the traffic arriving on port 80 and forward to the appropriate destination, depending on the target field in the TCP record (as I believe is done on public hosting sites, which have far more domains than available IPs). I've never needed multiple domains, but there may well be packages to handle this.

Comment: There are many ways to do this... but VPN is not involved in any of the ways ;-) You can ask your ISP for a solution, maybe it has a cheap one. Otherwise i'd recommend to go with a proxy. My preferred way for this would be to get a Mikrotic Router (i am not affiliated), it has everything built in. You can also just go with nginx like that https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0  Anyway, it will unfortunately cost you a lot of time :-(

Comment: @AFH i dont believe I can use separate ports, unless I'm missing something as my DNS won't allow me to set a port, just an IP address..  and i also feel like your answer had to do with subdomains, where as I want abc.com on 1 server and xyz.com on another server (no subdomains).  but I'm new to all of this so maybe I missed something?  i am also lost on how to forward the traffic from one internal ip to another internal ip?  is that something iis can do?  and thanks for your help!

Comment: @Harry what would I ask my ISP for?  would I need a second router?  ive read to ask for a 2nd public IP address, but I'm still confused how my router can split up traffic based on IP address, I'm only seeing setup for port forwarding (and i cannot control the port everything has to come in on 80).  curious what Mikrotic Router has that allows it to work, so I could see if my router has it?  Or at least know what feature to look for in a new router?  so it sounds like I might have to look into nginx, which is new to me, but it sounds like it's not simple to use?  thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Jesse - I don't think that the handling of multiple subdomains should be any different from multiple domains. I use the public host to add the port numbers. I've never needed to do the rerouting, so I don't know what packages handle it, and I can't comment on IIS, since I've not used it.

Comment: @AFH is right, sure you can use different ports, but the user has got to manually enter the port ithe browser in order to reach one of the websites... But i dont see how this is done on DNS level as the domain name does. Port related stuff is configured on your firewall/router that has got WAN connection. On the DNS server you just register one IP for both Domain names.

Comment: @Harry - By using the public host, I am able to add ports here, so that the web client is unaware that this is being done. I also use the facility to map an external port to a different port on the internal host, which not all routers can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are basically asking for is called "reverse proxy". A few solutions for you:

- **use webserver 1 as reverse proxy**

  - example for IIS https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis
  - example for apache: https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another
  - this solution is pretty bad because you add one more single point of failure: if webserver 1 reboots due to updates, webserver 2 is offline as well
- **install a reverse proxy** and configure your router to NAT port 80 from your WAN port to the proxy serve.

  - just as above, you add one single point of failure
  - example with nginx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240840/nginx-reverse-proxy-multiple-backends
  - example with a mikrotik OS : https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Multiple_Web_Servers (i am not affiliated with mikrotik) - as the routing device is also the proxy, you have one single point of failure less
  - install a firmware to your router that supports reverse proxy

Sure there are many more proxy servers you could use, but i recommend in first place nginx, you will find lots of tutorials and it is open-source

- **ask your ISP about a second static IP address**.

  - In my office, we have 4 static IP's, our ISP (cable) provided a propreitary Cisco device that has got 4 GBit Ethernets, each one providing one IP. It is about 10$ more per month than my private contract is. This way you have even one single point of failure less: your router hehe
- **serve both web applications on the same server or built a cluster**

  - why not? this way you could increase availibility of your proxy and webserver by building a cluster of your 2 hardware servers, example with proxmox https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_4.x_Cluster#Requirements (i am not affiliated with proxmox, it is open source anyway)

As we all love drawings, here some drawing :-)

[image]

Comment: thank you!! i'll go through all these references tonight!!