# Port 80 conundrum

Tags: port-forwarding

I have several devices on my home network that are accessible through non-standard ports (Openhab, Cameras, Grafana Charts, etc, etc, etc). For security reasons, I setup a web server so that I can funnel all communications through a single port. Since my ISP blocks traffic on ports 80 and 443, I had to use a non-standard port.

This solution works fine from most locations. The problem that I have now though is that my company only allows traffic on ports 80 and 443, so I cannot access my system from my office (which is where I need access 90% of the time).

Does anyone have any suggestions for bridging this divide? I’ve tried to forward my domain name (example.com) to my open port (myIP:Port#) and it appears seamless, I’ve also tried using an iFrame in an externally hosted web page.

Comment: In a related question I gave [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1274974/327367), and it seems to contain all the elements you need to implement a solution to your problem. If you think it's a promising solution, I'll tailor it to your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Set up a VPN.  This is liable to be significantly more useful, even if it's not as easy, because you can use it for more than just these web pages.  However, your IT department may not take kindly to someone running a private, unsanctioned VPN over their firewall (assuming they're competent that is, an incompetent IT department probably won't notice).
- Use an external open proxy server to bounce the connection off of.  This puts you at some risk in multiple ways (both data security, and your IT department), so I wouldn't' suggest it except as a last resort.
- Run your own external proxy server.  VPS hosting is really cheap (you can get one that will do this with no issue for 5 USD a month most places, or even less if you don't care much about performance).